# When using Spring/JPA and inserting initial data with data.sql, why is the ID column not auto-incrementing?

Tags: java, spring

Error:

```
Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data.sql]: INSERT INTO kana_term (id, en_term_text, jp_term_text) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'a', 'あ'); nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, a, あ).
```

Entity:

```
package io.blainelafreniere.langsite.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class KanaTerm {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO) private Long id;
    @Column String jp_term_text;
    @Column String en_term_text;
}
```

data.sql:

```
INSERT INTO kana_term (id, en_term_text, jp_term_text) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'a', 'あ');
```

I have also tried excluding the "(id) VALUES (DEFAULT)" stuff as well:

```
INSERT INTO kana_term (en_term_text, jp_term_text) VALUES ('a', 'あ');
```

And I get the same error.

I thought my entity was configured so that I didn't need to specify an ID.

Comment: Can you share your table create statement just to be sure.

Comment: what database are you using? Can you use identity?

Comment: @DanielJacob I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: @Silverfang this is the create table output: `create table kana_term (id int8 not null, en_term_text varchar(255), jp_term_text varchar(255), primary key (id))`

Comment: You could modify it to be `create table kana_term (id int8 not null AUTO_INCREMENT, en_term_text varchar(255), jp_term_text varchar(255), primary key (id))`

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my issue by changing `@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)` to `@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)`